# Kotlin Coroutine - is there a default timeout

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm trying to reach a server, which is occasionally slow. The ktor client I'm using is crashing with an `Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 15000 ms`, even though I never specified any limit. Is there a default timeout integrated?

Minimal example:

main.kt

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.features.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*


suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = HttpTimeout.INFINITE_TIMEOUT_MS
            connectTimeoutMillis = HttpTimeout.INFINITE_TIMEOUT_MS
            socketTimeoutMillis = HttpTimeout.INFINITE_TIMEOUT_MS
        }
    }

    val foo = client.get<String>("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/20000/url/http://www.google.co.uk")
    println(foo)

}
```

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    application
}
group = "me.oehmj"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_serialization_version: String by project
val kotlin_coroutines_version: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}
```

gradle.properties

```
kotlin.code.style=official
ktor_version=1.4.2
kotlin_coroutines_version=1.4.1
```

The Ktor-HttpTimeout-Module seems to have no effect.
Are there any suggestions on how I can prolong the Timeout time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-cio/io.ktor.client.engine.cio/-c-i-o-engine-config/request-timeout.html) you should do like that:

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    engine {
        requestTimeout = 0 // 0 to disable, or a millisecond value to fit your needs
    }
}
```

The default value is 15 seconds.

You can read more about ktor engines [here](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#cio)

[image]

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that there is also an engine-level configuration. Thank you very much!

Comment: When I tried to use 0, I got this: IllegalArgumentException: Only positive timeout values are allowed, for infinite timeout use HttpTimeout.INFINITE_TIMEOUT_MS

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:

```
return HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(HttpTimeout) {
        this.requestTimeoutMillis = 15000
    }
}
```